# Pivot data type error

Tags: pivot

I have a table which needs to do pivot as column to row, but getting data type error,
I have below table data

[image: I have below data]

Need to pivot and output should be like

[image: Need to pivot and output should be like]

I tried with query:

```
select prod As product_id , para As parameter_id
from
(
  select product_family_id,product_id,parameter_id 
  from product_family_exclusion
) d
pivot
(
  max(product_id) 
  for parameter_id in (prod,para)
) piv;
```

But getting error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to int. Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 The incorrect
>   value "prod" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

What I am missing about PIVOT table?

Comment: Please add your current query, copy and paste error message, and tag your DBMS. Have a look at this question about create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your sample output is correct for product_id 10211.  You seem to be missing parameter_id 416.

Here is an example of using dynamic SQL (in SQL Server) to solve the problem.  You could probably adapt it to other RDBMS's.  I took the liberty of generating unique column names for `parameter_id` because using the same column name might be problematic for the `PIVOT`.

```
--Demo setup
set nocount on
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsCoalesce AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
drop table if exists Table1
create table Table1 (product_family_id int, product_id int, parameter_id int)

insert into table1(product_family_id,product_id,parameter_id) values
(111,3227,334),
(111,3227,335),
(1112,10211,414),
(1112,10211,415),
(1112,10211,416),
(1112,10211,417),
(1112,11784,514),
(1112,11784,515),
(1112,11784,516),
(1112,11784,519)

--The solution
drop table if exists PivotTemp
select * into PivotTemp from 
(
select product_family_id, product_id, parameter_id, 'parameter_id' + convert(varchar(5),ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by product_family_id, product_id order by parameter_id)) as GeneratedParameterHeading from table1
)a
--select * from PivotTemp
SElect @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GeneratedParameterHeading) 
            FROM PivotTemp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
SElect @colsCoalesce = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 'coalesce(convert(varchar(100),' + QUOTENAME(c.GeneratedParameterHeading) + '),'' '') as ' + QUOTENAME(c.GeneratedParameterHeading)
            FROM PivotTemp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

print @cols
print @colsCoalesce
set @query = 'SELECT product_family_id, product_id, ' + @colsCoalesce + ' from 
            (
                select product_family_id
                    , product_id
                    , parameter_id
                    , GeneratedParameterHeading
                from PivotTemp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(parameter_id)
                for GeneratedParameterHeading in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

print @query
execute(@query)
```

---

```
| product_family_id | product_id | parameter_id1 | parameter_id2 | parameter_id3 | parameter_id4 |
|-------------------|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
| 111               | 3227       | 334           | 335           |               |               |
| 1112              | 10211      | 414           | 415           | 416           | 417           |
| 1112              | 11784      | 514           | 515           | 516           | 519           |
```

Comment: Hello Scott, thanks for your reply it's working fine.. but can we modify your query or in short without creating dynamic.

Comment: @KiranK - if your RDBMS is SQL Server, you could update the tag in your question to reflect that as it might help others.

Comment: @KiranK - as far as I know, the only way to address your problem is by using dynamic SQL.  There is not a fixed number of parameter_id's to `pivot` on.